# How can I stop Drupal from removing my line breaks in article text

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to create Drupal articles with a bunch of plain text files. But when I paste the file into the article all the line breaks ("\n") are stripped out.

How can I prevent this from happening. I would be happy for them to come across as "\n" because at least then I can write some JavaScript to format the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because HTML does not display line breaks (CR and LF). Drupal can convert them to HTML `<br />` tags so they appear as you can see in the text file.

In **Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats**, click "configure" next to the text format you use in the content type (or do this for all input types except PHP, if you have it).

Check "`Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>)` "

Then, move "Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. 
 and

)" under "Filter processing order" and make sure it's processed after HTML filters and URL processor.

[image: Filter settings]